# Xamarin architecture classes links breaks

Tags: hyperlink, architecture, break

I am new in mobile development and trying to learn it. I have started with default project type and add a new page in my view. In that page whenever i am trying to add a listviewit is showing me following error.
The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context
MyCoffeeApp D:\My Work\MyCoffeeApp\MyCoffeeApp\Views\CoffeeEquipmentPage.xaml.cs

I don't understand what i am doing wrong? where i am breaking the link within the architecture. [image]